# Android best practice - views/activities

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

Just starting out on android developing. To start off, I'm building an app which is gonna function like a gallery+image viewer, with the added functionality of quickly and swiftly moving pictures into subfolders, for easy sorting of lots of pictures.

So far I have 2 activites -  a full screen image view, and a full screen thumbnail grid (for multiselect purposes).

Now as I'm new at this, I was wondering if this dual-activity was a wise decision. Would it be better to simply switch between content views than to power up an entirely different activity when switching from image view to grid view (and vice versa).

What I'm looking for are of course the obvious pros and cons - performance, ease and usability. But also if there are more fundamental "pattern"/best practice reasons for one or the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your dual activity approach is sensible. Generally speaking the Android Activity/View APIs are structured around having a single fixed View per Activity. Although you can manipulate Views within your Activity's layout, I'd suggest this should be restricted to hiding/showing/moving Views rather than replacing the layout wholesale.

What you probably should consider is the newer [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). This can almost be though of as "activities within activities". A Fragment essentially allows you to wrap up an element of a UI (layout and behaviour) in a reusable component. So in your specific example, the two distinct UIs could be Fragments within a single activity.

This has a couple of benefits such as being able to reuse your UIs in other activities and you can do funky transition animations.

Comment: +1 for the Fragments API, I have not used it yet but it looks really nice. Thanks. Only available from API level 11 though (Android 3.0), that means it's a no-go for me. Too bad :(

Comment: I'm intrigued by the fragment. Exactly one of the things I wanted to do was animations in switching between image view and grid view - as I understand I'd be able to accomplish with fragments. Having both views in one activity would of course allow this, and also would allow me to reuse some common elements like menus, certain commonplace textviews etc. however, I like the code simplification of having them placed in seperate activities.

Comment: Actually, that simplication (or encapsulation) you're talking about is essentially just as clear-cut with a Fragment. Your activity simply becomes a container for your fragments.

Answer (score 1):

dual activity should work, as you won't be bothered by implementing the back button action.

Comment: Yes - preserving the behaviour of the back button is important.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I hadn't really thought about the back button. But seeing as my alternative was more "semantically enriching" via an actual "Go to Grid" button, which of course would mean more implementation, but would be more userfriendly, pros and cons :)

Answer (score 1):

Activities were made exactly for this purpose. If you prefer, you can have your whole application in a single activity with a custom layout engine (reload components, etc.) and that's what you want to do if you want a "portable" app (e.g. you develop an app with a common UI for various platforms, Andropid, Windows 7, iOS, etc.), but if you want to go Android only, the preferred way is to use the provided APIs, and not to reinvent the wheel. It works fine, and will give users a comforting sense of consistency in their experience (it will look and feel like other Android apps).

The current project I'm working on (a game) already has 10 different activities, and I'm planning more...